# How make a regular expression which replace the tags {{name}} with the value of an attribute of class named in that way

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I need a function with a regular expression that replace some tags with the value of an attribute or property in a class... I mean:
This is my class:

```
var myClass = new Object();
        myClass.id = 7;
        myClass.name = "My name";
        myClass.data = "Some text";
```

This is a string that I want replace

```
var myString = "<div data-id="{{id}}"><h3>{{name}}</h3><p>{{data}}</p>"
```

The function has to be something like that:

```
function formatElement(myClass, theString){

}
```

If I invoke the function with the class and myString it has to return:

```
"<div data-id="7"><h3>My name</h3><p>Some text<p>"
```

Thans to all

Answer (score 2):

This is easy with the function callback :

```
function formatElement(myClass, theString){
    return theString.replace(/{{(\w+)}}/g, function(_, s){ 
        return myClass[s];
    });
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/rerenenoti/1/edit)